# App Sandbox Not Enabled Error with Third Party Framework

Tags: macos

[image]

My app has sandbox enabled but when I validate it, it's still complaining about the "App sandbox not enabled".

[image]

> App sandbox not enabled. The following executables must include the
>   "com.apple.security.app-sandbox" entitlement with a Boolean value of
>   true in the entitlements property list: [(
>   "com.DreamCodeApp.TimelapseX.pkg/Payload/TimelapseX.app/Contents/MacOS/TimelapseX"
>   )] Refer to App Sandbox page at
>   https://developer.apple.com/devcenter/mac/app-sandbox/ for more
>   information on sandboxing your app.

The third party framework is a custom made one use to generate video from images and screenshot below is export summary.

[image]

Comment: did you know the answer ? because I am having the same issue here.